# Change id of clone children in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table on which I have a hidden line that I clone in order to add new lines dynamically.

```
var $clone = $('#table-invoicing').find('tr.hide').clone(true).removeClass('hide');
$('#table-invoicing').find('table').append($clone);
```

Each line have a id and a data-type.
The hidden line is set an id ending in 99.
I would like to change this id when I clone the hidden line.

I found similar topics, but for some reason I don't manage to include it in my script. When I clone the line, then there is 2 elements with same id, so a selector by id won't work.

I tried :

```
$clone.$('#invoicing-row-descr-99').attr("id", "newID");
```

but then it tells me that $clone is not a function.

Any idea ?

Comment: `$clone.find('#invoicing-row-descr-99').attr("id", "newID");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$clone.$('#invoicing-row-descr-99').attr("id", "newID");
```

> but then it tells me that $clone is not a function.

Because $clone is an object. Just use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr) or [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop) for the **cloned element**:

```
$clone.attr("id", "newID");//change cloned element id
```

---

As per your comment, use like this:

```
$clone.find('your_element').attr("id", "newID");
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem here is that I don't need to modify the tr id, but the td inside the tr. And there is 4 td inside

Comment: sorry, but not getting you.

Comment: As you can see, what I clone is the row by selecting tr :
    $('#table-invoicing').find('tr.hide')
But the id I would like to change is the id of the cloned td inside this cloned tr.  Sorry if it was unclear in my question

Comment: ah now it works!! thanks a lot!
If you have a minute, can you explain me why I can't use prop on find ?

Comment: sorry? you can use find. not?

Comment: oh and one more thing... sorry but still related to the issue.
I try to change the data of the td the same way I change the id :
       
    $clone.find('[data-date="99"]').data("date", idInsert);

But unfortunately that doesn't work :/ I guess it is a selector issue once again :/

Comment: yes I can use find, it works perfect, just wondering why using attr and not prop :)

Comment: you may use any. But want to know difference? Then look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 3):

[`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) Is a good practice in current versions of jQuery.

```
$clone.prop("id", "yourId");
```

You'll need to use it before you are appending it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use prop!

Comment: @VincentTeyssier here is a jsFiddle version if you need more help https://jsfiddle.net/msy9dgkg/

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually I know how to clone and use prop, but I explained my issue not very well. What I would like to change is the id of the cloned td that are inside the cloned tr.